# PC won't get past launch screen, no boot menu or BIOS

Tags: boot, bios

Since two days my pc has been unable to boot up. It gets stuck on the launch screen and just stays there for a long time without any change at all

[image]

attempting to access the BIOS to try a clean install of windows doesn't work either, it's just completely unresponsive. I've tried booting it up without the HDD connected and all that changes is the last line of the picture not being there; though trying to boot it up without the RAM will just cause it to beep repeatedly like an alarm clock would. Spamming the F1-F12 keys also has mixed results, at times it will take me to a screen with just a blinking line in the top left corner with the screen blinking too; then it can also just take me to a completely black screen though my monitor is still responsive, I've been unable to consistently recreate how to get to either of those states nor do I know which specific F key it was. All the cables and usbs work on another pc, I've tried resetting the CMOS of the mother board and making sure it's clean of dust as well but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas? Extra pictures can be provided if they're required.

As for some specs:
Motherboard : Asrock 980DE3/U3S3
Graphics card: Gigabyte GTX 750 ti
RAM: 2x4 Kingston hyper furyX
HDD: Toshiba DT01ACA100
OS: Windows 10
Power supply: LC600H-12 V2.31 - Office Series

UPDATE: I just got done trying a bunch of other things. I identified a couple of things which aren't the problem; the motherboard and RAM are fine I believe since trying to boot it up without RAM will just cause it to make that repeated beeping noise. I've tried two ways to reset the BIOS settings now, both taking out the battery for over four hours and also using the jumpers; neither of which did anything. I was trying to remove the graphics card too but I was unable to do that as I just couldn't find a clear method, nor was I able to find one online

UPDATE 2: After trying some other things involving moving the RAM sticks around I'm fairly certain I ended up messing up the power supply somehow, now it won't boot anymore at all. I've also sent a mail to the people who put the graphics card in so I can try and remove it for when the power issue gets solved.

Comment: It sounds like defective hardware. Its going to be hard to identify what hardware it is, but it could be your motherboard.

Comment: Are you sure you reset the BIOS settings? - remove the power and battery for ~30 minutes, then replace the battery and power up... or press the button if there is one.

Comment: Basically, it's "whatever next should appear in that list", though unless you have a clear recollection of what that is, it's not an easy diagnosis.

Comment: Also try reseating RAM and CPU... remove the graphics card if you have onboard video.

Comment: I just got done trying a bunch of other things. I identified a couple of things which aren't the problem; the motherboard and RAM are fine I believe since trying to boot it up without RAM will just cause it to make that repeated beeping noise. I've tried two ways to reset the BIOS settings now, both taking out the battery for over four hours and also using the jumpers; neither of which did anything. I was trying to remove the graphics card too but I was unable to do that as I just couldn't find a clear method, nor was I able to find one online.

Comment: Did you change or do anything right before this problem happened? Try it with just one stick of RAM and then just the other stick. Make sure the single stick goes in the right slot. The video card should be screwed in on one end (on the case edge) and the other end will probably have a clip that you need to push in order for it to come out. When you lift it to remove it, start with the end on the case and come out at a angle going up (assuming the case is lying flat).

Comment: I can't think of anything specific right before it happened nope. As for the video card I've looked and maybe I'm just an idiot but I genuinely couldn't find how it's connected, I also didn't want to mess with things too hard for fear of breaking things beyond repair; the other edge of the case (Backside of the motherboard) has an extra protective layer over it too so I would practically have to dismantle my entire computer to access it. I've tried calling the people who put this thing together but it looks like they're on holiday for the time being. I'll try the RAM anyway and will update.

Comment: ASRock what? What is the model of your motherboard? Pleased click [edit] and amend your question to add that. In fact, everything we need to know about your situation should be in the question, instead of in comments. Comments pile up and soon they scroll off the screen. When you answer anything, please [edit] your answer into the original question.

Comment: Given the symptoms, one of the first things you should try is just disconnecting all the drives completely, to see if it will come up far enough to get you into the BIOS.  But at this point, it sounds like you really need to go back to the system builder before you risk causing more damage.